# Server is up and running EDB Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Ya instalé PostgreSQL en versión 15 con su usuario y contraseña. Lo hice funcionar en el símbolo de comandos Shell, instalé el pgadmin4; igual haciendo funcionar el usuario y contraseña, hubo una herramienta que me salió del Stack Builder de EnterpriseDB Postgres llamado PEM-HTTPD, lo instalé y se suponía que fungiría como servidor web para administrar bases de datos de postgres, pero el problema es que solo me muestra la imagen de la marca EDB Postgres y un mensaje que dice *Server is up and running* y no hace nada más, no me lleva a alguna otra opción, no hay nada más que se pueda ver.

Entonces la verdad es que no sé cómo hacer funcionar dicho servidor y no funciona poniendo el puerto de dicho servidor creando un servidor dentro de pgadmin, ya lo intenté, no va por ahí. ¿Cómo hacer funcionar el server de pemhttpd de edb postgres? Porque me estoy imaginando que esta herramienta es una sustitución del localhost:51589 que antes era de postgres, porque ya lo intenté así también y no funciona tampoco.

Comment: Preguntale a EDB, me suena a una herramienta de la compañia que no es libre como pgadmin

Comment: No es evidente que tengas el PEM web server https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/pem/latest/pem_architecture/